# Creating a different instance of an Object with scope prototype in OSGi using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jetty, osgi, apache-karaf

It is a complicated problem so I will explain it as clear as I can. I have three `OSGi` bundles `A`, `B`, `C` deployed into `Apache Karaf`. I also have a security bundle which is used by those `A`, `B`, `C` bundles.

Each `A`, `B` and `C` bundles contains this:

```
<osgi:reference id="basicAuthHandlerFactory" interface="com.groupgti.security.handler.basicauth.BasicAuthHandlerFactory"/>

<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="basicAuthHandlerFactory"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="createSecurityHandler"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="java.lang.String">A.realm</value> <!-- The realm is depending on a bundle, A.realm, B.realm, C.realm -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`Spring` code snippet to get the security handler from security bundle. This handler in security bundle is exposed as an `OSGi` service and created in the security bundle like this:

```
<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler" scope="prototype">
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref bean="constraintMapping"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="strict" value="false"/>
    <property name="identityService" ref="identityService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="basicAuthSecurityHandler" class="com.groupgti.security.handler.basicauth.BasicAuthFactoryHandlerImpl"/>
<osgi:service ref="basicAuthSecurityHandler" interface="com.groupgti.security.handler.basicauth.BasicAuthHandlerFactory"/>
```

`BasicAuthFactoryHandlerImpl#createSecurityHandler(String realm)` is used to create the different instance of the security handler for each bundle. The realm is passed by the bundle when `createSecurityHandler` method is invoked by `Spring` `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` as showed in the above code.

The `securityHandler` `Spring` bean has a `scope` prototype, in which case when every call to the method `getBean` is called this should return a newly created object.

The realm I am setting for security handler is like this:

```
public class BasicAuthFactoryHandlerImpl implements BeanFactoryAware, BasicAuthHandlerFactory {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicAuthFactoryHandlerImpl.class);

    private BeanFactory factory;

    @Override
    public ConstraintSecurityHandler createSecurityHandler(String realm) {
        ConstraintSecurityHandler handler = (ConstraintSecurityHandler) factory.getBean("securityHandler");
        handler.setUserRealm(realm);
        LOGGER.debug("Security handler created. Got realm: {}", realm);
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.factory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

Handlers for each bundle gets created, everything is fine. But the problem is that the realm  for all bundles is somehow the same realm passed from the first started bundle. I am sure I am passing different realms in each `Spring` configuration in different bundles, but the realm is always from the first started bundle and it is not working correctly.

Does anybody have an idea where might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem why the same instance is shared across applications. All my bundles `A`, `B` and `C`, used this:

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="8020">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="5" maxThreads="15"/>
        <httpj:handlers>
            <ref bean="securityHandler"/>
            <ref bean="ipFilteringHandler"/>
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

to create the security handlers and for all of them `Jetty` used the same port `8020`. And it wasn't able to handle the different handlers on the same port. If I changed the the ports to be all different, everything worked. But that was not the solution for me. The solution was to make one realm to be used by all bundles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the single "securityHandler" from the beanFactory. So there is only one shared instance. Inside the createSecurityHandler you should create a new object and return it.

Comment: I tried that, that didn't work. There was still the same problem. The security handler has a scope prototype, so from spring documentation it should return a new instance of an object. The problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR the problem here is more the way spring does the proxying. Cause the proxying is done for the service Reference and not the service. You probably need to configure it correctly for using the right proxying.

I think something like the following will probably help:

```
ServiceReference nativeReference = ((ServiceReferenceProxy)serviceReference).getTargetServiceReference()
```